# BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT syntax error

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I'm using VS12 in my project and I'm defining a very simple class which serializes its attributes. However, when I put the `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` I obtain a syntax error:

```
syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
```

However, when I omit `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT`, everything works fine. I was wondering if it could depend from the template specialization used by `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT` (I've used `BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID` as well with the same error). Is there any bug in VS12 regarding this?

The snippet is:

```
namespace a { namespace b {
    class BaseSerialization {
        public:
            BaseSerialization(const std::string& functionName) : functionName(functionName) { }
            virtual void getFunctionName() const = 0;

        private:
            friend class ::boost::serialization::access;

            template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned int const file_version) {
                ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(functionName);
            }

        protected:
            std::string functionName;
        };

        class FOOZZ : BaseSerialization {
        public:
            FOOZZ(const std::string& functionName) : BaseSerialization("a"), functionName(functionName) { }
            virtual void getFunctionName() {
                int a;
            }

        private:
            friend class ::boost::serialization::access;

            template <class Archive> void serialize(Archive &ar, unsigned /*int const file_version*/) {
                ar & BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(functionName);
            }

        protected:
            std::string functionName;
        };
        BOOST_CLASS_EXPORT_GUID(FOOZZ, "FOOZZ")
// namespace a, namespace b
```

Comment: Take the [tour], read [Ask], and [MCVE]. Microsoft is the keeper of bugs for Visual Studio, you should ask them that question. If you post an MCVE however, we might be able to assist you.

Comment: Run your code through the preprocessor and you'll see why the preprocessor doesn't expect a `<` there